# Count single full stop and double full stops in a String using R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a sample string , like below

text = "it.. was a priority.  So..."

I need to count number of times a full stops occurs, and number of times two full stops occur and three full stops occur together.
For the above statement, I need my answer to be:

Count of Single Full stops: 1,
Count of two fill stops: 1,
Count of three full stops: 1

I use the R code : `stringr::str_count(text,"\\.\\.\\.")` --> this gives me count of 1 for three continuous full stops , **which is correct**.

Next I use: `stringr::str_count(text,"\\.\\.")` --> this gives me a value of 2, because another three set of full stops occur together. But I want this count to be 1 and the another set must qualify as 3 full stops together.

Likewise, I need the count of single full stop as '1' , but above code gives me 6, counting all together. How can I achieve this in R?

Thanks in advance.

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may qualify your full stop regex pattern using lookarounds which ensure that you get the correct count:

```r
stringr::str_count(text, "(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)", perl=TRUE)        # number of 1 full stops
stringr::str_count(text, "(?<!\\.)\\.\\.(?!\\.)", perl=TRUE)     # number of 2 full stops
stringr::str_count(text, "(?<!\\.)\\.\\.\\.(?!\\.)", perl=TRUE)  # number of 3 full stops
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the character to raw, then use `rle`:

```
dots <- rle(charToRaw(x) == 46)
```

Or equiavalent using `strsplit` instead if preferred:

```
dots <- rle(strsplit(x, '')[[1]] == '.')
```

Then we can use table to get the frequencies:

```
table(dots$lengths[dots$values == T])
# 1 2 3 4 
# 2 1 2 1
```

**Example data**

```
x = "alksj.lij...lkasjdf.asl;k..aslkd;l....as;lkd..."
```

Comment: Hi DWW, I did my undergrad at Cornell, see here: https://sg.linkedin.com/in/tim-biegeleisen-557aa38

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen cool - always nice to meet other Cornellians

Comment: thanks DWW... I think answer by Tim fits right into my requirement. But this is another way... helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

The following generalizes to any number of full stops in one line of code. It returns a list with the number of occurrences for each number of full stops.

```
library(tidyverse)

stops <- 1:3

map(stops, ~str_count(text, paste0("(?<!\\.)\\.{",.x,"}(?!\\.)")))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.